# IShuffleLayer applied to shape tensor must have 0 or 1 reshape dimensions: dimensions were [1,4]

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

I have a problem when converting onnx model to trt. My Environment:

```
ONNX IR version:  0.0.4
Opset version:    9
Producer version: 1.3
```

Converting a model leads to

````
[2020-01-16 07:04:54 WARNING] Setting layouts of network and plugin input/output tensors to linear, as 3D operators are found and 3D non-linear IO formats are not supported, yet.
[2020-01-16 07:04:54   ERROR] (Unnamed Layer* 314) [Shuffle]: IShuffleLayer applied to shape tensor must have 0 or 1 reshape dimensions: dimensions were [1,4]
[2020-01-16 07:04:54   ERROR] Builder failed while analyzing shapes.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Failed to create object```
````